# How to convert plain text files into JSON with NiFi...upstream values are separated by commas

Tags: apache-nifi, couchbase

I know this has been asked before but I cant seem to get the right processor configuration. I have a file flow config'd that reads plain text messages from an upstream bus with the goal of writing them into a Couchbase cluster as JSON.  Below is a snippet of the message showing its structure:

```
...type=osd osdop_cmpxattr=0,osdop_getxattr=0,osdop_other=0,osdop_delete=0,statfs_send=0,...
```

I have tried convert and replace processors but I cant seem to get it config'd correctly.  The end result is either a binary file or empty JSON file.

Comment: it's not a kind of any standard data format. probably you have to use script to transform to json.

Comment: @daggett correct, its plain text which NiFi identifies as such.  Im pretty sure there are NiFi processors that can handle the transform using regex or a scheme mapping, just havent been able to get it to fully work yet.

Comment: please edit your question add input example, desired output, and what have you tried so far.

Comment: I took your input and developed a custom script to achieve the end goal using the ExecuteScript processor